# Lost SSIS password - any way to open the package without the password?

Tags: ssis

Yes, I lost the password to an SSIS package in 2008 R2. Is there any way to recover the package? Has anyone been able to open a password protected package without having the password?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe package is set to run on SQLAgent?

Answer (score 4):

We had a recent problem where some developer who loved encrypting his SSIS packages with passwords forgot he even worked on it and it broke.

Luckily, (and as far as I know this is the *only* way) if your package is set up to run via a job on the SQL Agent you can recover the password like this:

```
SELECT sjs.command
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps sjs ON sj.job_id = sjs.job_id
WHERE sj.name = '<job name here>'
```

There will be a portion of the returned command that looks like 
    ".../DECRYPT -password here-"

Good luck!

Comment: I just did this against SQLServer 2012, and there was no DECRYPT in command the string.

Comment: I've got it! tnx very much

Answer (score 1):

No. If the encryption were reverseable then it wouldn't be much use, would it?

Chalk this up as yet another reason why encrypted packages are probably not that useful

Answer (score 0):

If the package is also stored SQL Server database ('MSDB' in the SSIS tree in Management Studio), you should be able to export it to the file system: right-click, Export, select 'File System'.

You'll lose any sensitive data (connection passwords) in the package, but I'm guessing that's not the biggest problem you have.